# Magnific popup: Get current element in callback

Tags: javascript, jquery, magnific-popup

In Magnific Popup, I want to get an attribute in the link that is clicked and use it in a callback function (using callbacks: open) to make some changes in the DOM.

How can I do this? For example, in the code below, it should return 'it works' to console. Instead it prints 'doesnt work'. Please help!!

```
<a href="#test-popup" class="open-popup-link" myatt="hello">Show inline popup</a>

<script src="jquery.magnetic.custom.js"></script>

<script>

    $(document).ready(function() {
      $('.open-popup-link').magnificPopup({
        type:'inline',
        midClick: true,
        callbacks: {
          open: function() {

            if ($(this).attr('myatt')=="hello") 
            { 
              // do something 
              console.log("it works");
            }
            else
            {
              console.log("doesnt work");
            }

          },
          close: function() {

          }
        }

      });
    });

</script>

<div id="test-popup" class="white-popup mfp-hide">
  Popup content
</div>
```

Answer (score 15):

For Magnific Popup v0.9.8

```
var magnificPopup = $.magnificPopup.instance,
              cur = magnificPopup.st.el;
console.log(cur.attr('myatt'));
```

Answer (score 6):

First, i recommend to you to use the data attribute ( data-custom="foo" ) or a known attribute.

HTML :

```
  <a href="photo.jpg" class="popup" data-custom="dsaad">Do it!</a>
  <a href="photo.png" class="popup" data-custom="mycustomdata">Do it!</a>
```

jQuery :

```
$('.popup').magnificPopup({
  type : 'image',
  callbacks : {
    open : function(){
      var mp = $.magnificPopup.instance,
          t = $(mp.currItem.el[0]);

      console.log( t.data('custom') );
    }
  }
});
```

I do not know if a better way exists. Actually you can read their documentation about public methods and you will see there. I tested the code above and everything works fine :)

Comment: To note the above only works for older versions of Magnific Popup. If you are using anything past version 0.9.8 please see @Konpaka answer below.

Answer (score 5):

For v. 0.9.9:

`this.currItem.el`

Answer (score 0):

```
// "item.el" is a target DOM element (if present)
// "item.src" is a source that you may modify
open: function(item) {}
```

and use data-attributes, to example data-myatt - that get:

```
$(this).data('myatt')
```

Answer (score 0):

The clicked element can be accessed within the callback using:

```
this.st.el
```

Inside the callback, "this" refers to $.magnificPopup.instance.

Under public properties:

*"magnificPopup.st.el // Target clicked element that opened popup (works if popup is initialized from DOM element)"*

Answer (score 0):

Also, inside `open: function(item) {}`, `this.content` might help.. It will return the div of the content being shown. useful with the `change: function () {}` as well. Hope it helps someone like me.