# Magnific Popup object

Tags: javascript, jquery, magnific-popup

**Magnific Popup**

I use Magnific Popup, a jQuery lightbox like plugin. I try to use the built in object to get an attribute.

**It does not work the way I thought it would. I've read the API here:**

http://dimsemenov.com/plugins/magnific-popup/documentation.html#api

**What I tried so far**

I get the object in the console but I can't get an attribute from it. (the jquery ready looks a bit different (alias) because it's used in WordPress)

```
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $('.image-link').magnificPopup({
        type:'image',
            callbacks: {
                open: function() {
                    var magnificPopup = $.magnificPopup.instance;
                    console.log(magnificPopup.currItem);
                    window.location.hash = $(magnificPopup.currItem).attr('data-slug');
                    }
            }
    });
});
</script>
<a href="http://www.someimage.com/image.png" data-slug="my-slug">
```

Own thougts

- This is not an object like $(this) and will not work the same?
- I call it the wrong way?
- I use the wrong object for this problem?

**Question**

How is it done correctly?

Answer (score 7):

`currItem` is a Magnific Popup data object, it's not a DOM element. This object contains data about opened element - image path, flags if it's loaded or not  e.t.c.

You can access DOM element that opened popup via `$.magnificPopup.instance.currItem.el`.

Also, if you're executing the code from `open` callback, you can use `this` instead of `$.magnificPopup.instance`:

```
this.currItem.el
```

Answer (score 0):

After publishing my post I found a related post that solved this problem:

[Magnific popup: Get current element in callback](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16885863/magnific-popup-get-current-element-in-callback)