# How can I access the calling object in the popup definition?

Tags: jquery, this, magnific-popup

Using Magnific Popup, I'd like to access the data attributes of the calling object/link so that I can pass it in to the popup using POST. Code:

```
$('.editRecord').magnificPopup({
    type: 'ajax',
    preloader: false,
    ajax: {
        settings: {
            method: "POST",
            data: {
                recordID: $(this).data("recordid"),
                field1: $(this).data("field1"),
                // similar with the rest of the fields
            }
        }
    }
});
```

This doesn't work because `$(this)` seems to actually refer to the document object.

I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16885863/magnific-popup-get-current-element-in-callback) and have tried all the suggestions in the answers, but none seem to work as this is not in a callback, it's in the settings. Have tried:

```
recordID: $.magnificPopup.instance.st.el.data("recordid")
```

and

```
recordID: $.magnificPopup.instance.currItem.el[0].data("recordid")
```

But I get error messages that `$.magnificPopup.instance.currItem` and `$.magnificPopup.instance.st` are undefined. `$.magnificPopup.instance` is defined, but I don't see any attribute that holds the current item.

How can I access the calling object from within the MagnificPopup definition?

Answer (score 0):

You may use `updateStatus` event and change the settings when status is `loading`, it fires right before the ajax call.

```
$('.editRecord').on('mfpUpdateStatus', function(e, statusObj) {
    if(statusObj.status === 'loading') {
        var instance = $.magnificPopup.instance,
            currEl = instance.currItem.el;

        // modify settings object
        instance.st.ajax.settings.data = {
            something: currEl.data('something') 
        };

    }
});
```

Above can be also added as a callback http://dimsemenov.com/plugins/magnific-popup/documentation.html#api

Comment: Tried adding the updateStatus as a callback and it never fires.

Comment: used beforeOpen instead and it worked. But had to use `instance.st.el` rather than `instance.currItem.el`